# Simple project keep crashing Blender on new computer. Why?

Tags: rendering

Got a new computer with double 2080TI and 64 gb RAM. Trying to render an image of this project. But Blender just hangs up when render and then crashes. Both in Cycles and Eevee.

Ant clues why this is? Running Blender 3.6.

https://blend-exchange.com/b/yNGn6oer

Comment: Your small rocks have _Displacement_ modifiers and level 6 subdivision. Too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be on 28 objects named 'Rock' that are under an Empty named ''Empty bord med mugg och mer''

The rest renders just fine

Comment: (.. which are level-6 subdivided.)

Comment: Thanks buddy! That fixed the problem. Although... why was it a problem?! The Rocks had different sequential names...(?)

Answer (score 2):

You have some serious issues you need to fix. I mean if you are giving a lot of vertices to small objects that are supposed to add small minor details, like little rocks or handles or this caterpillar, then that's definitely a geometry optimization issue that can cause some serious performance overhead. The caterpillar alone has 50k vertices after using the Subdivision modifier which is totally unnecessary. Be careful with subdivision modifiers, don't set the level too high and try to resort to Shade Smooth too. It seems like you just threw some random objects you got from the net into your scene without regard to their geometry, and then you end up with 500k vertices scene that could have easily been less than 10k, and crashing your software.

[image]

Comment: Nope. Nothing changed when deleting the heavy verticies objects. Fully aware of this and just testing stuff out here. Trying to keep vertyicies down usually when working more serious. And no: I always model every single bit of my stuff myself so no random objects from the net.

Comment: The rocks had 6 level subdivisions. That's pretty heavy and a no-no :)